# Call grandparent method in grand child class

Tags: python, super

Sorry, may be this is silly question, but its very confusing to me. Let's suppose we have the following classes:

```
class A():
 def say(self):
   print("A")

class B(A):
 def say(self):
  print("B")

class C(B):
 def say(self,*args, **kwargs):
  return super(C, self).say(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am accessing parent method in child, and it prints `B`, but I want to access method from class `A` as we are getting access from class `B`.

I know we can add `super` in class B, but I don't want to modify class `B`. so is there any option to get method from `A` directly in class `C`?

Comment: You can call directly method say of class A by A.say() - from within the say() method of class C.

Comment: @PeterMajko you need an instance of A to do that. Sanjay - why would you want to do such a thing? on one hand you're using inheritance and on the other hand you're trying to break it. Better post *what* you want to accomplish, not *how* you're trying to do it. There might be better ways to achieve your goals

Comment: In class C, your say() method can access A by `super(B, self),say()`

Comment: I see, I forgot "self" as an argument :) A.say(self)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can by calling `A.say(self)` like this:

```
class A():
     def say(self):
         print("A")

class B(A):
     def say(self):
         print("B")

class C(B):
     def say(self):
         A.say(self)
         B.say(self)
         print("C")
```

Then to test it out from a terminal:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.say()
A
>>> b = B()
>>> b.say()
B
>>> c = C()
>>> c.say()
A
B
C
```

Note: I dropped the `args` and `kwargs` because the `A` and `B` classes didn't use those arguments. If you wanted to make `say` take those all the way up though simply call `A.say(self, *args, **kwargs)` and if `A.say` returns something you can return it too

Comment: This can work as well I think, as more general approach: super(super(self.__class__, self), self).say(*args, **kwargs)